# Several kinds of clones and comparisons in java

Tags: java, copy, comparison

I am working on a complex datamodel in which we have different classes with lots of attributes that we sometimes need to compare or copy partially. However, we couldn't gather them in a class because some of them overlap.

So you can better understand, let's take an example:

```
public class Product {
  private Amount price;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private Color color;
  private Shape shape;
  private Picture mainPicture;
  private Company designer;
  private Company maker;
}
```

Let's imagine the production is outsourced and we sometimes need to copy everything but maker:

```
public Product copyForOutsourcing(Product product) {
  Product p = new Product();
  p.setPrice(product.getPrice());
  p.setName(product.getName());
  p.setDescription(product.getDescription());
  p.setColor(product.getColor());
  p.setShape(product.setShape());
  p.setMainPicture(product.getMainPicture());
  p.setDesigner(product.getDesigner());
  return p;
}
```

Let's now imagine the product exists in multiple forms and we sometimes need to copy everything but shape, color and picture:

```
public Product copyForDeclension(Product product) {
  Product p = new Product();
  p.setPrice(product.getPrice());
  p.setName(product.getName());
  p.setDescription(product.getDescription());
  p.setDesigner(product.getDesigner());
  p.setMaker(product.getMaker());
  return p;
}
```

The same way, we need different comparisons: p1.get*().equals(p2.get*()).
As you can see, it's a bit redundant and it's still worst when there are more attributes and/or more copy or comparison methods. Moreover, when adding an attribute, we always forget adding it in the copy and compare methods.

The first idea we got was to add annotations:

```
  @Outsourcing, @Declension
  private Amount price;
  @Outsourcing, @Declension
  private String name;
  @Outsourcing, @Declension
  private String description;
  @Outsourcing, @Declension
  private Color color;
  @Outsourcing
  private Shape shape;
  @Outsourcing
  private Picture mainPicture;
  @Outsourcing
  private Company designer;
  @Declension
  private Company maker;
```

That way, it's easy to compare or copy attributes using reflection, there is not redundant code, and when adding attributes, it's easy to update copy and compare methods: we just have to add annotations to the new attribute.

But what happens if Product extends an other class, let's say CompanyObject, in which attributes like "stockingLocations" should be copied in copyForDeclension.
CompanyObject shouldn't depend on annotation Declension because this annotation is Product specific. CompanyObject could even be in an other project and so couldn't be modified.

If we want to use reflection so as to avoid redundancy, then we need to specify which attributes are copied:

```
public List<Field> getDeclensionAttributes() {
  List<Field> list = new ArrayList<Field>();
  list.add(ReflectUtils.getField(CompanyObject.class, "stockingLocation"));
  list.add(ReflectUtils.getField(Product.class, "price"));
  ...
  return list;
}
```

The problem is that this way, we have attribute names specified as String so refactoring will probably break things and the compiler will not warn us!

So the question is: when having a class with many attributes in which several copy/comparison methods need to be specified, what is the most elegant way to implement these copy and comparison methods?
Furthermore, how to ensure that adding an attribute forces the developer to question the behavior of this attribute in the different copy/compare methods?

Comment: Well , if you are using spring , you can design custom product factory class which can give you the product object based on your requirement.

Comment: It might make more sense to annotate what you DON'T copy (e.g. @NotCopiedForDeclension).

Comment: For comparison use multiple implementation of  java.util.Comparator interface as inner classes in your Product Domain.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can have only one copy implementation and control what attribute to copy by passing List of attribute to copy (Enum to represent attribute list). Something like this

```
public Product copyForDeclension(Product product, List<ProductAttributes> attribuitesToCopy) {
    attribuitesToCopy.stream().forEach(productAttribute -> {
        switch (productAttribute) {
            case PRICE:
                //do copy
                break;
            case NAME:
                //do copy
                break;
            default:
                // throw exception, will be helpful for maintain code
        }

    });
}

enum ProductAttributes {
    PRICE,
    NAME,
    //.....
}
```

This way implementation will be common and non-redundant and what all attributes to be considiered will be handled by caller of copy (This may be good or bad for your requirement).

Comment: The problem is that if we have a class MyProduct which extends Product, it will have to list all the attributes of Product in its own enum MyProductAttributes so we still have redundancy.

Comment: only one enum can be kept say ProductAttributes this will have attributes for Product and hierarchy